# scraping part of website in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, telegram

I want to scrape part of this website http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/ , expecially the description, command should reply as

```
"Equipped with a diverse selection of arrows, deft hands, shroud of stealth and an exalted bow, the crafty Ivara infiltrates hostile territory with deception and diversion, and eliminates threats with a shot from beyond. Ivara emerged in Update 18.0."
```

and nothing else, maybe can be useful set a sort of `<p>` I want to print.
For now I have this, but it doesn't reply what I want.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Ivara')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
for sub_heading in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(sub_heading.text)
```

Comment: There are a ton of "p" elements on that page, it's not surprising that your script generates a lot of output.

Comment: yes, i know, the part "if text:
    print text should print the first one it find in that page

Comment: does what you trying to scrap have some unique class/id

Comment: no, but i just updated the code, now it answer right, but with too much things. Still alot better, now it responds at least with what i'm trying to scrape

Comment: The example that you'd like to scrape is not in the URL you've provided.

Comment: it's at the line under "Release Date: December 3rd, 2015"

Comment: a perfect workaround can be limit the 'p' tags that bs4 finds, for example i write "4", it should print the first 4 'p' tags it find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the solution @Andersson provided (it won't work for all heroes as there is no `Release date` for everyone) and @SIM's comment, I'm giving you a generalized solution for any hero/champion (or whatever you call them in that game).

```
name = 'Ivara'
url = 'http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/' + name
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
main_text = soup.find('div', class_='tabbertab')
print(main_text.find('b', text=name).parent.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
Equipped with a diverse selection of arrows, deft hands, shroud of stealth and an exalted bow, the crafty Ivara infiltrates hostile territory with deception and diversion, and eliminates threats with a shot from beyond. Ivara emerged in Update 18.0.
```

For other heroes, just change the `name` variable.

One more example with `name = 'Volt'`, Output:

```
Volt has the power to wield and bend electricity. He is highly versatile, armed with powerful abilities that can damage enemies, provide cover and complement the ranged and melee combat of his cell. The electrical nature of his abilities make him highly effective against the Corpus, with their robots in particular. He is one of three starter options for new players.
```

**Explanation:**

If you inspect the page, you can see that there is only 1 `<b>hero-name</b>` inside the `<div class="tabbertab" ... >` tag. So you can use the `<b>...</b>` to find the text you need.

Comment: definitely  resolved my question and hinted me how to structure it inside my telegram bot. Really really thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use index of target paragraph and get required text as

```
print(soup.select('p')[4].text.strip())
```

or fetch by previous paragraph with text `"Release Date:"`:

```
 print(soup.findAll('b', text="Release Date:")[0].parent.next_sibling.text.strip())
```

Comment: Sir Andersson, should it not be more specific: `print(soup.find_all('b', text="Ivara")[0].parent.text.strip())`? +1 for your answer.

Comment: @SIM, `"Ivara"` is a text of `h1` which located in another block of nodes - it will be hard to set relationship between that `h1` and target `p`

Comment: @Andersson, isn't `soup.findAll(...)[0]` the same as `soup.find(...)`?

Comment: This solution solves OP's specific question, but by this `I want to scrape part of this website http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/ , expecially the description` I guess he wants a generalized solution. I've posted a solution using yours'.